# calculating cagr with starting and total value in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets-formula

Normally, we calculating CAGR with this formula
[image]

I have the begin and total value and time periods, but I don't have the final value

- begin value: 10
- total value: 500
- time: 6 month

this is the calculation method to find the CAGR:

```
total value / begin value = c + c^2 + c^3 + c^4 + c^5 + c^6

c = 1 + cagr
```

now I need to calculate something like that in google sheet

Answer (score 0):

```
=POWER(total+1,time_in_months/12) * begin
```

For your example, it gives the result: 223,83